# How to determine which lightdm greeter is in use?

Tags: scripts, lightdm, login-screen

For those who don't know, greeter is basically the login screen. In case of Lightdm specifically, there are several versions of it:

- unity-greeter
- kylin-greeter
- lightdm-gtk-greeter
- lightdm-kde-greeter
- lightdm-webkit-greeter
- razorqt-lightdm-greeter

#### The goal:

I need to know how to obtain the greeter version currently in use. Scripting solutions are most welcome ( preferably python, shell scripts, perl ) but also open to C code. Ideally , the solution would work like so:

```
$ ./get_greeter
kylin-greeter
```

#### Issues and failed approaches:

- Checking process listing doesn't work. I have kylin-greeter in use right now, but `pgrep -f lightdm | xargs -L 1 ps -o args --no-header -p` or  `pgrep -f kylin | xargs -L 1 ps -o args --no-header -p` return nothing that points to `/usr/sbin/kylin-greeter`
- `lsof -p <LIGHTDM_PID>` also provides no insights - no `/usr/sbin/kylin-greeter` among the listing.
- Parsing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` is a potential, but not ideal solution, since some flavors of Ubuntu ( such as Kylin ) won't explicitly state greeter session in that file.  I would prefer something more reliable.
- `gsettings` doesn't provide a reliable means of determining greeter in use either - presence of schemas for `unity-greeter` doesn't mean I am currently using that.
- examining paths and methods on `org.freedesktop.DisplayManager` service for system bus provided no insights into what greeter is in use either.

Comment: There are lots of answers here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Greeter

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  those all tell me what is available, but not what is being used currently

Comment: Does this help?  `grep -i exec= /etc/alternatives/lightdm-greeter`

Comment: @Terrance nope, that also doesn't do it. It gives `Exec=lightdm-gtk-greeter` , even though I'm using `kylin-greeter`. I switched to `lightdm-webkit-greeter` to test, but it still shows the same line

Comment: OK, I tried.  Good luck!  I hope you find the answer my friend!

Comment: @Terrance thank you for the efforts , I do appreciate any help. I'll probably put bounty on the question in 2 days, so keep an eye on it. If you  find something, feel free to post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a couple of quick tests, it seems the only way is to ask LightDM itself:

```
$ lightdm --show-config |& awk -F= '/greeter-session=/{print $2}'
kylin-greeter
```

I started testing with default Ubuntu, then installed `lightdm-gtk-greeter` and the installed `kylin-greeter`. In each case, it returned the correct option. For example, after editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to add `greeter-session=unity`, the output changed:

```
$ lightdm --show-config |& awk -F= '/greeter-session=/{print $2}'
unity

$ lightdm --show-config
   [LightDM]
A  backup-logs=false

   [Seat:*]
B  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
C  guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
D  user-session=ubuntu
I  greeter-session=unity
F  xserver-command=X -core
I  autologin-guest=false
I  autologin-user=muru
I  autologin-user-timeout=0

Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
C  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
D  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
E  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
F  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
G  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
H  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/95-kylin-greeter.conf
I  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Note the source of the configuration.

Comment: Nice find there!  It is interesting that there are so many configuration files.  I didn't even stop to look there.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Well for ubuntu based systems and all others were update alternatives works in your script you can run `update-alternatives --list lightdm-greeter |head -n1`  to see what they are using as the lightdm greeter. This should at least show the default lightdm greeter. I do know if your script could end up being broken by a user stopping lightdm and launching it with a non defualt greeter however I cannot see a logical reason to do this. If you want more information on this see man update-alternatives. If you do not pipe the result of that output to head and have it only display the top line it will show all of the lightdm greeters installed.