# How can I find out my greeter name

Tags: xorg, display-manager

I'm new to Linux. Is there a way to find out the name of my greeter (where you sign in) or whether I have many installed (a way to find apps by function: greeters, text editors, terminals, etc...)?

Comment: Maybe this might help:  https://askubuntu.com/q/870054/231142

Comment: @Zanna yes, I think you are right. I was confusing sign in with sign up :/

Answer (score 9):

The greeter (screen) is provided by the display manager.

Assuming you are using X server (not Wayland, Mir or others), you can find your default display manager from the file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

If you have started a display manager manually for the current session and display, you can check where the X server has stored the authentication cookie (this is typical for all display managers i have come across including `lightdm`, `mdm`, `gdm`):

```
% pgrep -af Xorg
1050 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

`/var/run/lightdm/root/:0` suggests my current display manager is `lightdm` on display `:0`. Match your display manager and display accordingly.

You can also do `pgrep -af dm` but that can get you false positive (i.e. you would not get any conclusive result) for multiple displays.

---

After you find the display manager in operation, you can dump the running configuration of the DM to get the greeter, for example for `lightdm`:

```
% lightdm --show-config
   [LightDM]
A  backup-logs=false

   [Seat:*]
B  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
C  guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
D  user-session=ubuntu
E  greeter-session=unity-greeter
F  xserver-command=X -core
G  autologin-guest=false
G  autologin-user=
G  autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Here my greeter session is `unity-greeter`, now check the `unity-greeter` binary's source for all the gory details.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using lightdm, You can use this simple `dpkg` command to find out the greeters you installed. These are usually cli applications and you won't find them by searching in Unity dash or something like this.

```
dpkg -l *greeter*
```

This may return something like this

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                  Version         Architecture    Description
+++-=====================-===============-===============-================================================
un  lightdm-greeter       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
ii  lightdm-gtk-greeter   2.0.1-2ubuntu4  amd64           simple display manager (GTK+ greeter)
ii  lightdm-gtk-greeter-s 1.2.1-0ubuntu1  all             settings editor for the LightDM GTK+ Greeter
un  lightdm-kde-greeter   <none>          <none>          (no description available)
ii  pantheon-greeter      3.1.1-0~r532+pk amd64           Pantheon Login Screen
ii  remix-greeter         0.5.5.4~xenial  all             budgie-remix based lighdm-webkit2-greeter
ii  unity-greeter         16.04.2-0ubuntu amd64           Unity Greeter
un  unity-greeter-session <none>          <none>          (no description available)
```

The entries with `ii` are the ones you have installed.

As far as I know, only `lightdm` have many variants of greeters, which are actual binary programs invoked and used by `lightdm`. Other display managers such as `sddm` or `gdm3` uses their default one and provides options for changing some look and feel such as background pictures, themes etc. They are not standalone programs like the ones for lightdm.